# Spring JPQL get rows between date time

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get records from a database and I use java.util.date and java.util.calendar, to retrieve records inserted in previous 5 minutes from now I compute the interval using java.util calendar however when both dates start and end are parsed, I am not able to find rows in the timespan I am looking for, any advise to remediate the concern?

```
    Date d = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    // SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    d = cal.getTime();
    String stdate = sdf.format(d);
    //System.out.println("start date" + stdate);        
    // process end date     
    Date dd = new Date();
    Calendar call = Calendar.getInstance();
    call.setTime(dd);
    call.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -0);      
    dd = call.getTime();
    String eddate = sdf.format(dd);
    SimpleDateFormat sdft=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
    //SimpleDateFormat sdft=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String stabledate=sdf.format(new Date());       
    
     List<customers> listofcustomers= customerepo.findAllByTscsstatusAndDateBetween("ACTIVE",sdf.parse(startdate),sdf.parse(enddate));e here
```

Comment: Please don't use `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They're obsolete and troublesome. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … 
    , 
    OffsetDateTime
    .now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) 
    .minusMinutes( 5 )
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

`Date` & `Calendar` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Determine the moment five minutes ago.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes( 5 ) ;
Instant fiveMinutesAgo = instant.minus( d ) ;
```

Your database column must be of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Convert our `Instant` object for use with SQL.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = fiveMinutesAgo.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM event_ 
WHERE when_ !< ?
;
```

Pass our `OffsetDateTime` object to fill-in the placeholder.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Comment: I am using Mysql8 datetime(6) data type

Comment: @ehirwa `DATETIME` is the wrong data type. That type holds a date with a time but no offset. Without the context of an offset-from-UTC, that type cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. In MySQL 8, you should be using `TIMESTAMP` to represent a moment. `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL 8 is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. (Caveat: This is my understanding from a quick read of the reference documentation. I am not a MySQL user.)